# Enhanced Ecommerce: Product Category "not set" in the Product Performance card

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

The following is the Google Analytics JavaScript code executed on an e-commerce (captured with [GA Debug](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna)), for a quite simple purchase process.

#### 1) Navigate to the Home Page

```
ga("create", "UA-NNNNNNN-1", "auto")
ga("require", "ec")
ga("require", "ec")

ga("require", "ec")
ga("set", "&cu", "EUR")

ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "488", name: "Light Coral", list: "Home Page list", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "4.50", brand: "Coral", position: 1})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "487", name: "Light Purple", list: "Home Page list", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "4.50", brand: "Purple", position: 2})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "489", name: "Light Pink", list: "Home Page list", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "4.50", brand: "Pink", position: 3})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "491", name: "Light Red", list: "Home Page list", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "4.50", brand: "Red", position: 4})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "717", name: "Light Blue", list: "Home Page list", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "6.00", brand: "Blue", position: 5})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "768", name: "Light Pink 2", list: "Home Page list", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "8.00", brand: "Pink", position: 6})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "92", name: "Light Green", list: "Home Page list", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "5.95", brand: "Green", position: 7})
ga("ec:addImpression", {id: "712", name: "Light Orange", list: "Home Page list", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "6.50", brand: "Orange", position: 8})

ga("send", "pageview")
```

#### 2) Click on one product (on the Home Page) > Open the product page

```
ga("ec:addProduct", {id: "717", name: "Light Blue", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "6.00", brand: "Blue", position: 5})

ga("ec:setAction", "click", {list: "Home Page list"})

ga("send", "event", "UX", "click", "Home Page list")

ga("create", "UA-NNNNNNNN-1", "auto")
ga("require", "ec")
ga("require", "ec")

ga("require", "ec")

ga("require", "ec")

ga("require", "ec")
ga("set", "&cu", "EUR")
ga("ec:addProduct", {id: "717", name: "Light Blue", brand: "Blue", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "6"})
ga("ec:setAction", "detail")

ga("send", "pageview")
```

#### 3) Add the product to the cart

```
ga("ec:addProduct", {id: "717", name: "Light Blue", brand: "Blue", category: "Some/Category/Path", price: "6", quantity: "1"})

ga("ec:setAction", "add")

ga("send", "event", "UX", "click", "Add to cart")
```

#### 4) Go to the checkout page

```
ga("create", "UA-NNNNNNNN-1", "auto")
ga("require", "ec")
ga("require", "ec")

ga("require", "ec")
ga("set", "&cu", "EUR")

ga("ec:addProduct", {id: "717", name: "Light Blue", price: "6.00", brand: "Blue", category: "Some/Category/Path", quantity: 1})

ga("ec:setAction", "checkout", {step: 1})

ga("send", "pageview")
```

#### 5) Follow the checkout process

```
ga("ec:addProduct", {id: "717", name: "Light Blue", price: "6.00", brand: "Blue", category: "Some/Category/Path", quantity: 1})

ga("ec:setAction", "checkout", {step: 2})
ga("send", "pageview")
ga("ec:addProduct", {id: "717", name: "Light Blue", price: "6.00", brand: "Blue", category: "Some/Category/Path", quantity: 1})

ga("ec:setAction", "checkout", {step: 3})
ga("send", "pageview")
ga("ec:setAction", "checkout_option", {step: 3, option: "Send to another address"})
ga("send", "event", "Checkout", "Option")
ga("ec:addProduct", {id: "717", name: "Light Blue", price: "6.00", brand: "Blue", category: "Some/Category/Path", quantity: 1})

ga("ec:setAction", "checkout", {step: 4})
ga("send", "pageview")
ga("ec:setAction", "checkout_option", {step: 4, option: "BRT"})
ga("send", "event", "Checkout", "Option")
ga("ec:addProduct", {id: "717", name: "Light Blue", price: "6.00", brand: "Blue", category: "Some/Category/Path", quantity: 1})

ga("ec:setAction", "checkout", {step: 5})
ga("send", "pageview")
ga("ec:setAction", "checkout_option", {step: 5, option: "banktransfer"})
ga("send", "event", "Checkout", "Option")
ga("ec:addProduct", {id: "717", name: "Light Blue", price: "6.00", brand: "Blue", category: "Some/Category/Path", quantity: 1})

ga("ec:setAction", "checkout", {step: 6})
ga("send", "pageview")
```

#### 6) Conclude the purchase

```
ga("create", "UA-NNNNNNNN-1", "auto")
ga("require", "ec")
ga("require", "ec")

ga("require", "ec")

ga("require", "ec")
ga("set", "&cu", "EUR")
ga("ec:addProduct", {id: "717", name: "Light Blue", price: "6.00", brand: "Blue", category: "Some/Category/Path", quantity: 1})
ga("ec:setAction", "purchase", {id: "16O00000011", revenue: "16.00", shipping: "10.00"})
ga("send", "pageview")
```

#### The problem

From Google Analytics dashboard, within the *Ecommerce* section, when I go on the Product Performance card (*Product Performance > Product name > Product SKU*) I have a `(not set)` value under **Product Category**:

[image]

While in *Overview > Product Category* I can see the right **Product Category** of the product:

[image]

Furthermore, if I go on *Product Performance*, select *Primary Dimension: Product Category (Enhanced Ecommerce)*, then click on the category, I can see the product in this table.

What am I doing wrong?

Why, inside the product performance card, is the Product Category `not set`?

Comment: Same problems here. Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @mavi91 not yet, sorry..

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this answer to fix the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24401449/3554477

This mostly happens because Magento allows one product to be linked with multiple categories and hence GA can't decide or track the category(ies) associated with the particular product.