# One product, two paths, two templates in magento. Why?

Tags: magento

I have a product with full path like domain.com/category/product.html and the same product with canonical path domain.com/product.html.
I use 3 columns to display this page.

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
  <label>Catalog Product View (Any)</label>
  <!-- Mage_Catalog -->
  <reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns-2.phtml</template></action>
  </reference>
  <reference name="content">
    ....
  </reference>
  <reference name="right">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
  </reference>
  <reference name="left">
    <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftmenu" before="-" template="catalog/navigation/menu.phtml"/>
  </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

This settings works for both path (I can see  in view-source), BUT left column is empty for canonical path. Why??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having different URL's for the same product like domain.com/category/product.html and domain.com/product.html is because of the settings you've made in Catalog configuration. If you would like to use URL's like domain.com/product.html only, you can set it in **Settings** menu, under the **Catalog**, open the **Search Engine Optimizations** tab and set **Use Categories Path for Product URLs** value to **No**.

About your question; first read my answer about having multiple categories for a product [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18053742/how-to-get-category-name-of-current-product-on-product-detail-page-in-magento/18055084#18055084)

Your product view page must have a category related data in **left** block, therefore if you click on a URL like *domain.com/category/product.html* your session has a category id and your left block is rendered normally. If you click on a URL like *domain.com/product.html*, your session doesn't have a category id, so your left block looks empty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I found a row in my menu.phtml:
if (!Mage::registry('current_category')) return;
It was my fault! Thanks one more and sorry that you spent your time!

Comment: I am glad that you've found a solution. Don't be sorry, we are all here to help each other. Have a nice week!